# What is difference between "git push" and "a pull request"?

Tags: git, github

I already figured out the following part of workflow of git: you do git add and then git commit and then git push. The git push step basically publish your changes to the github. So what is this next step commonly referred to as "pull request"? Suppose that I'm not "forking" or anything advanced. And suppose that I work on a new branch I created (named "dev") other than the master branch. And I did the add, commit, push all under this new branch and did not do any "merge". How do I do a "pull request" and what is that step supposed to accomplish beyond git add, commit, push. Does that just mean I merge "dev" to "master"?

Comment: Look at the documentation for pull requests on GitHub.

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests

Answer (score 8):

Yes. That means merging the code to master.

In a general scenario many developers work on a repository and not all of them have push access to master. This means they cannot push the code directly to master. Hence, developers push the code to a different branch and then raise a pull request to merge the changes to master. An administrator then reviews the code changes in the pull request and then approves the request and merges the changes to master if the change looks good.